# JSON Schema for mobile application development

Tags: javascript, json, forms, mobile, jsonschema

I am researching technologies for use in building a set of mobile applications with some lightweight traditional CMS authoring capabilities around JSON content.

Given the availability of JSON schema for defining "content types", I'd like to find Javascript frameworks that make it very easy to build and render content entry, editing and display forms for mobile apps.

Does anyone have any recommendations on Javascript libraries and complementary server-side technologies that make this easy to do?

I've taken a look at jQuery Mobile for the web framework and have seen a number of "forms" plugins for jQuery but most of them seem oriented around handling the HTTP post and response (and making it easy to work with the data).  However, I haven't found anything with a real bend toward JSON Schema forms (model validation, view generation, layout, etc).

YUI is a nice framework and I'm pretty impressed with inputEx (http://neyric.github.com/inputex) so that seems like a plausible option for YUI.

Does anyone have any JSON-schema development experience for mobile apps and Javascript frameworks?  I'm curious if anyone has toyed with JSON-schema using tools like Titanium and what their experiences have been like.

Answer (score 0):

InputEx has now added [JSON-Schema support](http://neyric.github.com/inputex/examples/json-schema.html) in its current beta (as of this writing).

It should be noted that [JSON-Schema is only a draft IETF specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zyp-json-schema-03), of which there are currently three substantive revisions, all of which have now expired. Bear in mind the schema is not necessarily stable, and likewise the libraries that implement it. If a new version does appear, it could require you to make code changes to maintain compatibility with the approved standard/latest draft standard.